# How to Add a Distribution List Item to a Distribution List?

Tags: vba, outlook, distribution-list

I am attempting to add multiple child distribution lists as members of a parent distribution list through Outlook 2010 VBA.

The basic code that [Sue Mosher](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/adding-distribution-list-distributionlist-distlistitem-t2141961.html) posted online (where objItem is the child DL, as discovered via a For/Next loop) is:

```vb
Set objRecipient = Application.Session.CreateRecipient(objItem.Subject)
objRecipient.Resolve
objDistributionList.AddMember objRecipient
```

This is adding the child DL as "contact" rather than a member linking to the original child DL.
When I open the member, which is supposed to be the child DL within the parent DL, it appears as an email contact with an "UNKNOWN" email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that in the Outlook Object Model.
You can try to use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) (I am its author), which exposes [RDODistListItem](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDODistListItem.htm).`AddContact` method - it will let you pass `ContactItem` as well as `DistListItem` object as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry. I'd like to avoid using Redemption, as requiring such would necessitate my involvement as this thing gets used by other users.

Comment: Are concerned about other applications that use Redemption and can potentially cause conflicts? You can use RedemptionLoader (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/security.htm#redemptionloader) - this way the dll does not even need to be registered in the registry and you can deploy it by copying it longside your app.

Comment: The concern is more about dissemination of the workbook - I don't know who might use it down the road and let's just say it's not going to be in the hands of the most technically savvy people in the firm.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it actually **is** possible to do this within VBA, though it is a bit roundabout and I can't decipher why it works.

By adding a child distribution list to the 'to' field of a Mail Item object, it resolves the recipients of the Mail Item to a distribution list. You can then add those recipients to a parent distribution list. Note that this requires the Child List to still exist separately, ie. if the Child List is deleted, the Parent List will not be able to find it

```
Sub NestedDistLists()
    Dim outApp As Object
    Dim outMail As Object
    Dim distRecipients As Object
    Dim distListChild As Object
    Dim distListParent As Object

    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outMail = outApp.createItem(0)
    Set distListChild = outApp.createItem(7)
    Set distListParent = outApp.createItem(7)
    Set distRecipients = outMail.recipients

    distListChild.dlName = "Test Child"
    distRecipients.Add "john@example.com"
    distRecipients.resolveall
    distListChild.addmembers distRecipients
    distListChild.Save
    outMail.to = distListChild

    distListParent.dlName = "Test Parent"
    distListParent.addmembers distRecipients
    distListParent.Save

    distListParent.display
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is so bizarre. I don't have time to check if it works for the next week (or two; I no longer support the same group that needed it [6 years ago!]), but I hope someone else can verify in the meantime.

Comment: @variant Fair enough, it is indeed bizarre how it works. I know I get frustrated when I can't find a solution so hopefully this helps some other poor soul down the road